# div tag translate and i don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is my first question on stackoverflow, hope to do it right.

so, the problem is that i want to put 2 div per row 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eoHf.png

but when i add the fourt , the third and the fourt go down one row each.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSzZv.png

i've tried to play with magin-top but it kinda works only if the second div has 1% more than the other one (and that is non what i want).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eoHf.png

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row-progetti-explorer">
        {% for p in all_p %}
            <div
                {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
                    class="div-progetti2"
                {% else %}
                    class="div-progetti1"
                {% endif %}
                >
                <h3>
                    <a href="{% url 'War:detail' p.pk %}"><b>{{ p.nome.title }}</b></a>
                </h3>
                <p style="border-bottom: 1px solid darkgreen">Category:
                    <a href="{% url 'War:explore' p.categoria_primaria.name %}">{{ p.categoria_primaria.name }}</a>
                    {% for c in p.categoria_secondaria.all %}
                         <a href="{% url 'War:explore' c.name %}">{{ c.name }}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                </p>
                <a href="{% url 'War:detail' p.pk %}">
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="{{ p.img.url }}">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}





.row-progetti-explorer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.div-progetti1{
    border: 2px solid darkgreen;
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
}

.div-progetti2{
    border: 2px solid darkgreen;
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: palegoldenrod;
    color: black;
}
```

as i said i what 2 div per row (first link)

Comment: .row-progetti-explorer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.div-progetti1{
    border: 2px solid darkgreen;
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    background-color: red;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.div-progetti2{
    border: 2px solid darkgreen;
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 8%;
    background-color: palegoldenrod;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's an extra margin on your div-progetti2 class. You can check using Inspector of your browser.
Here's a tutorial on how to you use chrome inspector:

https://www.templatemonster.com/help/use-google-chrome-web-inspector.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be help you, but you just need to redecorate or modify this code as per your language. **this is front end only** as per rules, and you can modify instead of `<hr/>` tag to *border bottom*`.header` class

```css
.row-progetti-explorer {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1140px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .div-progetti2 {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
        }

        .main-content {
            padding: 2%;
        }

        .header {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .img-responsive {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
```

```html
<div class="row-progetti-explorer">

            <div class="div-progetti2">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h3> Dummy Title </h3>
                        <p>category: dummy</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="img">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="img">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="div-progetti2">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h3> Dummy Title </h3>
                        <p>category: dummy</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="img">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="img">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="div-progetti2">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h3> Dummy Title </h3>
                        <p>category: dummy</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="img">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="img">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="div-progetti2">
                <div class="main-content">
                    <div class="header">
                        <h3> Dummy Title </h3>
                        <p>category: dummy</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="img">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="img">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            
    </div><!-- end .row-progetti-explorer -->
```